# Rails + Heroku + Bonsai still try to connect 9200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bonsai-elasticsearch

I attached a screenshot([error screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA67N.png)
) which indicates the error.

> Faraday::ConnectionFailed in Devise::SessionsController#create
>
> Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 9200

I am using bonsai with ruby on rails and deployed to heroku.
But it still tries to connect to local 9200.

I have initialiser file as below.

**config/initializers/bonsai.rb**

```
require 'elasticsearch/model'

if ENV['BONSAI_URL']
  Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new({url: ENV['BONSAI_URL'], logs: true})
end
```

Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: You should add the error message in your question, not an external image

Comment: Thank you very much for comment. I tried to add image but stackoverflow does not allow me to do it as I am too new for the site(actually just signed up...). Hope you can see this screen shot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AA67N.png

Comment: Ah I understand what you suggested above. Thanks for the edit suggestion. will add the error msg in question from next time. I'm too noob clearly haha.

Answer (score 0):

the issue occurs on bonsai < 6.1 only. So please remove or upgrade current bonsai addon on heroku. Then try again